# why bindservice still causes app ANR after moving it to a worker thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a bindservice in onCreate that takes a long time, I tried to solve this problem by moving it to a worker thread, but it still causes the UI to wait. What can I do

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Recognizer.class);
                bindService(serviceIntent, mConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            }
        }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your description, it seems that calling `bindService` within UI thread is not the root cause of ANR. You should instead, call `bindService` without spawning user thread. One main reason is that, this causes memory leak.

When there is configuration change, as long the the thread still alive, it doesn't give chance to `Activity` for performing garbage collection. This is because your user thread is still holding reference to `Activity`.

The ANR root cause should come from `Recognizer` or `mConnection`. If you can post the implementation details of them, this can help us to help you.

Ask yourself the following questions

1. Are you performing any I/O intensive task in mConnection's `onServiceConnected`?
2. Are you performing any I/O intensive task in Recognizer's `onCreate`?
3. ...

Comment: Thanks Cheok, I think I've found the cause, it's in onCreate(). I have been doing too much in it, instead of onBind()

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, the problem is not in your `Activity`, but in your `Service`. Your `onBind()` call is taking too long and `onBind()` is called on the main (UI) Thread. You are doing too much work in the `onBind()` call. What you need to do is to move your initialization of your `Service` out of the `onBind()` call and into a separate background thread. To prevent the client from using the `Service` before it has been initialized, you'll need to keep a flag for each bound client which indicates if the background thread has completed the initalization. If the client tries to use the `Service` before it is ready (ie: completely initialized) then you can return some error code or throw a suitable exception.

Remember that lifecycle calls in all Android components (`Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`, `ContentProvider`) all run on the main (UI) thread and must run quickly.

Comment: "What you need to do is to move your initialization of your Service out of the onBind() call and into a separate background thread" - What does this mean exactly, can you illustrate it with code? onBind needs to return an IBinder so how can you move the initialization out of onBind?

Comment: @Justin The `IBinder` is just an object that you return. It doesn't need to be completely initialized when you return it. If it needs a lot of initialization then you set a member variable to `false`, spawn a background thread to do the initialization, and when the initialization is complete set the variable to `true`. If the client tries to use the returned `IBinder` before the initialization is completed, you'll need to throw an exception or return some kind of error code that means "I'm not ready yet".

Answer (score -2):

The problem is not in your Activity. You said that your bind service takes long time. So you must create thread inside the onBind method of your service.

```
public class ClientService extends Service
{
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent)
    {
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                // Your code here
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: aha, and what IBinder do you return, huh?

Comment: A) what's the difference between spin the thread off in activity and service. As far as I can see. it's basically the same. B) How can I return an IBinder object in worker thread in onBind method as you mentioned

Comment: This code is even not bildable